# Hyperbolic translation flow

Tags: differential-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

I am reading a paper which the author defines $\left\{ T_r \right\}$ as a hyperbolic translation along a geodesic $\gamma$ in the hyperbolic plane $\mathbb{H}^2$ with $\gamma(0) = 0$ such that $T_r (\gamma(0)) = \gamma(r) \ \  \forall r \in \mathbb{R}$.

I know that the hyperbolic translation depends on a curve and a point (I saw the definition of the hyperbolic translation in the book  "Introduction à la géométrie hyperbolique et aux surfaces de Riemann" on page 76). In this case, I see $T_r$ depends on the parameter $r$.

Would you help me understand this definition? How do I understand the  hyperbolic translation $T_{r_1} (x)$ for a $x \in \mathbb{H}^2$ and $r_1 \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: $T_r(x)$ is: translate from a given point $x$ of the oriented geodesic $\gamma$ at unit speed in the positive direction for time $r$.

Comment: This question (and my answer) should probably be moved to Math Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us work in $U = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : \textrm{Imag}(z) > 0 \}$: the upper half plane model of $\mathbb{H^2}$.  Note that $G = \textrm{SL}(2, \mathbb{R})$ acts on $U$ by Möbius transformations; the action is by isometries.  Consider the matrix
$$
T_\lambda = 
\pmatrix{
\lambda & 0 \\
    c   & 1/\lambda}
$$
where $\lambda$ is real and (say) greater than one.
[Note that here I am using slightly different notation that in the original question.  The "translation distance" of $T_\lambda$ is *not* equal to $\lambda$.]
It is an exercise to check that $T_\lambda$ is a hyperbolic element of $G$.  Also, its axis $I$ is the positive imaginary axis in $U$.  It is a further exercise to compute the *translation distance* of $T_\lambda$ restricted to $I$.

Let $L_\theta$ be the euclidean ray in $U$ that makes angle $\theta$ with $I$. It is an exercise to check that $T_\lambda$ also preserves $L_\theta$.  It is a further exercise to compute the translation distance of $T_\lambda$ restricted to $L_\theta$.  You should also check that $L_\theta$ is *equidistant* from $I$: that is, there is a fixed constant $d(\theta)$ so that every point $z \in L_\theta$ is distance $d(\theta)$ from some point $z' \in I$.

These equidistant lines $L_\theta$ answer your question.  It is a final exercise to transport the above discussion to a general hyperbolic element $T \in G$.

Comment: Thank you, Sam Nead! Would you help me with another question? Is the curve $\alpha(\lambda) := T_{\lambda}$ a geodesic?

Comment: That is a path in $G$, not in $U$.  I thought you were interested in geodesics in the hyperbolic plane?

Comment: Ah - I see.  In my answer, I am using a somewhat different notation from yours.  In any case, if you work through the details, it should answer your question.